# Yocto: Nothing provides python-bsddb needed by python-db-2.7.16-r1.cortexa7t2hf-neon

Tags: python, yocto, ros, bitbake

I'm trying to build [meta-ros](https://github.com/ros/meta-ros/tree/thud-draft) image for toradex colibri imx7 using pre existent colibri layers.

But when I try to build an image:

```
bitbake core-image-ros-roscore
```

I get the following error:

```
Collected errors:
 * Solver encountered 1 problem(s):
 * Problem 1/1:
 *   - nothing provides python-bsddb needed by python-db-2.7.16-r1.cortexa7t2hf-neon
 * 
 * Solution 1:
 *   - do not ask to install a package providing ros-core
```

The bblayers I am using:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
    ${META_RASPBERRYPI_LAYER} \
    ${META_ROS_LAYER} \
    ${META_LAYER} \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-toradex-nxp \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-freescale \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-freescale-3rdparty \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-toradex-tegra \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-toradex-bsp-common \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-gnome \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-xfce \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-initramfs \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-lxde \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-browser \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-qt5 \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-qt5-extra \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-rust \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-freescale-distro \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-toradex-demos \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-toradex-distro \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/meta-yocto/meta-poky \
    ${META_COLIBRI}/../layers/openembedded-core/meta \
"
```

Comment: Does your python PACKAGECONFIG contains bdb? see [here](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python_2.7.16.bb#n46) and [here](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python_2.7.16.bb#n185)

Comment: @Nayfe Yes. It does.

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: You need bitbake recipe for `python-bsddb` and include the layer. Looks like meta-python doesn't have this recipe. You may need to add one.

Comment: @Parthiban Normally, `python-bsddb` is provided by `python_2.7.16.bb` recipe if `bdb` packageconfig option is selected.

Comment: @Nayfe python_2.7.16.bb is only present in openembedded-core/meta/python, should it be included in meta-python too? I edited my post with the bblayers I am using.

Comment: Usually, I include `OE-core` from [poky layer](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta). If you don't want to use `Poky`, including [openembedded-core layer](https://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta) is maybe enough but i'm not sure. Can you try `bitbake -e python | grep ^PACKAGECONFIG`?

Comment: When I run this command the result is: ```PACKAGECONFIG=" "```. So I guess bitbake is not using the python_2.7.16.bb that has bdb, right?

Comment: Maybe one of the other layer overrides it, you can check for `python_%.bbappend` files (or with `bitbake-layers show-appends`)

Comment: @Nayfe it worked. I used ```bitbake-layers show-appends``` to check which files it was using, and de facto it didn't have ```PACKAGECONFIG ?= "bdb"``` and ```RDEPENDS_${PN}-modules_remove = "${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'bdb', '', '${PN}-bsddb', d)}"```. So I added those lines and it worked. Thank you for your help!